# ASP.NET MVC: Output format of jQuery UI Autocomplete (display value label key pairs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have the following idea, but I can't find any code snippets or similiar examples so I don't know if it's possible to do it with jQuery UI. So in my database I have a table, in which every customer has an ID and Name:

```
ID        Name
1         John Example
2         Johnny Example
```

What I want to do now is, if the user types Joh it should show him the entries in the following way:

```
John Example - 1
Johnny Example - 2
```

So my question: is it possible at all to do a display like that for my autocomplete function?

My code for the view and autocomplete function at the moment looks like this and displays only the name of the customer:

```
<script>
    $("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
        source: "/Customer/AutoCompleteCustomer",
        minLength: 2
    })
</script
```

Thanks and if you need any further information, please let me know, I will provide it as fast as possible.

Comment: Of course this is possible, you just need to make sure `AutoCompleteCustomer` returns data in this format. Is there more specific question here?

Comment: Do you have a code snippet just for the jquery ui part, how I would display the data there? The return of the right format of my Method is of course my duty.

Comment: There is no need for a snippet. I posted an answer to explain

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at [jQuery docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> There are two supported formats:
>
> - An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> - An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ...]

and later, when talking about making request to server for data

> For example, if the source option is set to "http://example.com" and
>   the user types foo, a GET request would be made to
>   http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be in the same format
>   as the local data described above. The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu.

So, as long as your server takes care to return data as either a string array:

```
["John Example - 1", "Johnny Example - 2"]
```

or an object array:

```
[{label: "John Example - 1", value: "1"}, {label: "Johnny Example - 2", value:"2"}]
```

jQuery autocomplete will be able to pick it up and display it the way you need.

Comment: Thanks for that wonderful example, I will try to do it this way and if my solution is ready or I have anymore questions, I will post them here :)

Comment: @RawMVC, sure, although if your new questions are of a different nature I would advise posting a separate topics for them. The SO policy is "one question per thread"